# SQL: Find next row in a where clause given an ID

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pagination

I have a table called `products` in a MySQL database. `products` looks some what like this:

```
id   name     din        strength active deleted
1    APA TEST 00246374   25       1      0
4    APA BOB  00246375   50       1      0
5    APA TIRE 00246888   50       1      0
7    APA ROT  00521414   100      1      0
9    APA APA  01142124   100      1      0
6    APA CODE 00121212   150      1      0
8    APA SERV 00011145   600      1      0
```

Obviously I've left out several columns not important to my question. When I query this table, I will be sorting by one of several different columns (The user interface allows individual users to change the sorting column and order), and I may have a search clause in which case I'll do a LIKE clause on NAME and DIN.

What I want to know is, given the sorting info and search info, and the ID of a specific product (Say I searched for 004, which returned 3 results, and I am viewing one of them), how could I get the next and previous products?

I need to do this, because if a user clicks to edit/view one of the products after searching and sorting results, they want to be able to cycle through results without going to the previous page.

Is there a good and efficient way to do this in SQL, or am I best off using PHP? Any ideas are also welcome.

Currently using this SQL query, which is experiencing issues if I sort by the `strength` column as there are duplicate values

```
SELECT T.*
FROM `wp_products` T
INNER JOIN `wp_products` curr on curr.id = 38
   AND ((T.strength = curr.strength and T.id < curr.id)
    OR (T.strength > curr.strength))
WHERE T.active = 1 AND T.deleted = 0 AND (T.name LIKE '%%' OR T.din LIKE '%%')
ORDER BY T.strength ASC, T.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

My PHP code (using WordPress) (Designed to get the next item)

```
    $sql = 'SELECT T.*
FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'apsi_products` T
INNER JOIN `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'apsi_products` curr on curr.id = ' . $item->id . '
   AND ((T.' . $wpdb->escape( $query['orderby'] ) . ' = curr.' . $wpdb->escape( $query['orderby'] ) . ' and T.id > curr.id)
    OR (T.' . $wpdb->escape( $query['orderby'] ) . ' > curr.' . $wpdb->escape( $query['orderby'] ) . '))
WHERE T.active = 1 AND T.deleted = 0 AND (T.name LIKE \'%' . $query['where'] . '%\' OR T.din LIKE \'%' . $query['where'] . '%\')
ORDER BY T.' . $wpdb->escape( $query['orderby'] ) . ' ' . $query['order'] . ', T.id ASC
LIMIT 1;';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have a reference to the current record, and then progressively look for the next record based on the sorted columns.  The example below assumes it is sorted on

```
ORDER BY Active, DIN, NAME
```

First:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE NAME LIKE '%X%' AND DIN LIKE '%%'
ORDER BY Active, DIN, Name
LIMIT 1;
```

Next: (***make sure you separate the `CURR.ID = 6` and the AND-ORs with proper brackets!***)

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE T
INNER JOIN TABLE CURR ON CURR.ID = 6 # the current ID being viewed
   AND ((T.Active = Curr.Active AND T.DIN = Curr.DIN AND T.NAME > Curr.Name)
     OR (T.Active = Curr.Active AND T.DIN > Curr.DIN)
     OR T.Active > Curr.Active)
WHERE T.NAME LIKE '%X%' AND T.DIN LIKE '%%'
ORDER BY T.Active, T.DIN, T.Name
LIMIT 1;
```

A working sample presented below

```
create table products
(ID int, SEED int, NAME varchar(20), DIN varchar(10), ACTIVE int, DELETED int);
insert products values
(1,  0,    'Product #1', '004812', 1,    0),
(2,  0,    'Product #2', '004942', 0,    0),
(3,  0,    'Product #3', '004966', 1,    0),
(4,  0,    'Product #4', '007437', 1,    1),
(5,  2,    'Product #2', '004944', 0,    0),
(6,  2,    'Product #2', '004944', 1,    0);

SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE active = 1 AND deleted = 0
ORDER BY din DESC, ID desc;

Output:
"ID";"SEED";"NAME";"DIN";"ACTIVE";"DELETED"
"3";"0";"Product #3";"004966";"1";"0"
"6";"2";"Product #2";"004944";"1";"0"
"1";"0";"Product #1";"004812";"1";"0"
```

If current is the row with ID=6, the next record can be retrieved using

```
SELECT T.*
FROM products T
INNER JOIN products curr on curr.ID = 6
   AND ((T.din = curr.din and T.ID > curr.ID)
    OR (T.din < curr.din))
WHERE T.active = 1 AND T.deleted = 0
ORDER BY T.din DESC, T.ID ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, I've always been terrible with SQL. Should I leave references to CURR as is, or should I change CURR and TABLE to my table names?

Comment: TABLE is a placeholder for your table name. CURR and T are aliases - leave them alone.

Comment: I am not having success without your query, more than likely I am doing something wrong. My query looks like this: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE active = 1 AND deleted = 0 ORDER BY din DESC` and when I run your query I get the first row returned by my query even though I am using the 5th ID that was returned. I should get the ID 38 from the 6th ID. Ideas?

Comment: @Rogue - added bracketing around the AND-ORs. please see edited answer

Comment: @cyberkiwi Thank you very much, the new query you posted works like a charm.

Comment: Small issue, your code doesn't work if one of my sorted columns has duplicate values. It skips and only shows one of each value. Any ideas?

Comment: @Rogue - that's why I explicitly added the T.ID ASC (assuming ID is the PK) at the end, so that it will include that as an explicit tie-breaker. Hope that helps

Comment: I figured as much, but it still isn't working properly. I updated my question to show a table much closer to mine, with the exact version of your query I am using. Right now, I would view ID 1 and the next row would be 4, then 7, then 5 and then 8.

Comment: @Rogue because you're going ASC on the ID, it needs to be `T.id > curr.id`

Answer (score 1):

Without a persistence cache layer like [memcached](http://memcached.org/), where you can store the results and get it without reissuing the query, a simple solution can be enabling the [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) in mysql. In this way, if the cache isn't invalidated from other querys, when you reissue the query the cost of pulling the result will be lowered

Comment: it can be done efficiently using just one query. See my answer

Comment: @cyberwiki from what I understand from the question, it's not a single query problem, since the items will be requested from different pages. Your query will address how to query for the different items, but will be re-evaluated for each page request, do you agree?

Comment: Yes, but with proper indexing, each limit 1 retrieves only 1 record as required, efficiently. Each SO page load requests about 10 items at least from the db, so round trips should be a minor concern.

Comment: @cyberkiwi I agree with you and I like your solution, we've analyzed the problem proposing two different optimization strategies. Anyway +1 from me :)

Comment: +1 If the resultset to retrieve is small, then persistence and caching could be an option

Answer (score 1):

For each displayed result, setup the *next* and *previous* links with the appropriate ID's.

The sort order can't be changed from the details view.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting Question.  I don't think you can do it in one query, but you can pull it off perhaps with three.

The first query pulls the answer row.  The trick would be to hold on to the value for the column they sorted on.  Let's assume this is "SortedColumn" and the value is "M".  Let's say the id of the row you got was 10.

Your second query would be the same as the first, but would be "top 1" and would add to the where clause "...and sortedColumn >= 'M' and id <>  10"  This gets you the next row.  You may want to return 10 rows and hold on to them to prevent doing this over and over.

To get the previous, switch your ordering to descending, and the where clause you add is "...and sortColumn <= 'M' and id <> 10".  This gets you the previous row.  Again, 10 rows may be more useful to your user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this quickly I don't believe it can work. Say I am sorting by the name column. The part `name` >= 'PRODUCT NAME #3' for instance doesn't seem to work