# PHP SQL Get Next Row in Query (with user ordered results)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pagination

I brought this [question up previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867230/sql-find-next-row-in-a-where-clause-given-an-id), but the answer I received only worked in some cases, but not for most of them.

I have a page that displays a list of products. I have 5000+ products, and the page they are displayed on have sorting and searching ability. The user could sort by any one of 5-6 columns, in Ascending or Descending order. They could sort by the 'Strength' column, which has many duplicate values. Even the 'Name' column has duplicate values.

Because of these sorting controls, I could have results with IDs of 5, 2, 8, 4 or something. I save the query vars in a session, so if I edit product 5, after saving it takes me to product 2, which after saving takes me to 8 and then 4. I need a query to get the next row after the current item ID.

The query I am using to test to get the results is:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE `active` = 1 AND `deleted` = 0 AND (`name` LIKE '%APO%' OR `din` LIKE '%APO%') ORDER BY `name` ASC, id ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

I have entered both a search value and am just sorting by name. How can I get the next row and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to pass the position in the results table in the URL. I get this by retrieving the page number, multiplying it by the number of results per page, and then adding an incrementing variable to it. This way, the previous/next links can take the query position and add/subtract 1 from it. Combined with an LIMIT statement, this appears to be working. It's annoying to have to pass the variable in the URL, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this out of the database.  Save the order of some number of the query ids in the session as well?  Then you can easily navigate through them.  If the person goes to resort the set, or you go beyond the limit of the stored data set, then reissue the full query and save a new set of results.

Answer (score 0):

The following query would return the second result

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE `active` = 1 AND `deleted` = 0 AND (`name` LIKE '%APO%' OR `din` LIKE '%APO%') ORDER BY `name` ASC, id ASC LIMIT 1,1
```

The following query would return the third result

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE `active` = 1 AND `deleted` = 0 AND (`name` LIKE '%APO%' OR `din` LIKE '%APO%') ORDER BY `name` ASC, id ASC LIMIT 2,1
```

and so on...

Or you could make a temporary table.  Temporary tables are tied to the database connection session.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE list ...
```

Comment: This solution won't work at all, as I have the item ID, not the position in the returned query